# Using an image map and a link on the same image

Tags: html, anchor, imagemap, area

I have images with dynamically generated image maps. I want users to be able to click on the map and be taken through to the `<area href=` property.

However, when they click on the background (i.e. not in any of the map's areas) I want them to go through to a background URL.

So my code looks something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeithHenry/C39g8/)):

```
<a href="fromAnchor.html" target="_blank">
    <img src="image.png" usemap="#test" />
</a>

<map name="test" id="test">
    <area href="fromMap.html">
</map>
```

In Chrome/FX it works as I expect - if I click in the `area` tag's shape I get taken to `fromMap.html`, if I click elsewhere I get directed to `fromAnchor.html`.

However, in IE (tested up to IE10) clicking on the `img` but outside the `area` does nothing. It does show the URL hint in the bottom left corner, but it doesn't follow the `a` tag.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution, but it's kind of awful (so would be very happy to see a better answer).

My workaround is to dynamically add a fallback `<area>` that fills the entire image and let clicks outside the exiting area's fall back to it:

```
var msie = /MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent);
if (msie)
{
    // Don't do this hack twice
    $('map[data-iehack!="1"]').each(function ()
    {
        // First find the image this map applies to
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.attr('name');
        var $img = $('img[usemap="#' + name + '"]');

        // Then find if the image is in an <a> tag
        var $link = $img.parents('a');
        if ($link.length > 0)
        {
            // If there is an <a> add an extra <area> that fills the image
            var wrapLink = $link[0].href;
            var width = $img.width();
            var height = $img.height();
            var $fallbackArea = $('<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,' + width + ',' + height + '" />');
            $fallbackArea.attr('href', wrapLink);
            $this.append($fallbackArea);
        }

        // Flag this map so we don't add it again
        $this.attr('data-iehack', '1');
    });
}
```

This example is in jQuery but the principal should work in other frameworks.

There has to be a better way than this - and this hack has to check the browser as I can't figure out how to detect IE's failure here.